# temp tables & web application

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop a web application for work, using PHP, MySQL and jQuery.

The main aim of the application is to store information about the work we do for our customer, so that we can give them detailed reports at the end of the year.

an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- a report would be created, using a customers details
- entries would be added to this report documenting the work that has been carried out.
- then both, report & entries would be inserted into there actual tables

I'm wanting to use temp tables to store the information so that I can use it between pages but looking to see if this is the best way of accomplishing this.

Thanks

D

Comment: Hi David - your question is too vague to be answered in it's current form. Please be more specific about the data that needs to be cached between page requests.

Answer (score 3):

Temporary tables are deleted automatically when the connection to the database is closed. In PHP, this is usually done after each page request. Use normal (i.e. non-temporary) tables to gather report data for all customers. Use foreign keys to link reports to customers and report entries to reports.